# Rails best practice: translations for in models and controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, rails-i18n

When I implement a translation for my rails apps, I often get to the point that I have defined some strings in the models or in the controllers that I also want to translate.

For example **in controllers** the flash notices or alerts when I use redirects:

```
redirect_to events_path, notice: 'All events deleted.'
```

or

```
def redirect_back!(message)
  (message != '' and message != nil) ? redirect_to(:back, alert: message) : redirect_to(:back)
  rescue ActionController::RedirectBackError
    redirect_to root_path, alert: 'Please allow in your browser the transmission of the referer.'
end
```

**In models** I use very often enumerations (since rails 4.1) and define for them a method that retuns a readable string for the enumeration. For example:

```
def readable_status
    if self.unprocessed?
        return 'Unbearbeitet'
    elsif self.processed?
        return 'In Bearbeitung'
    elsif self.completed?
        return 'Korrigiert'
    elsif self.rejected?
        return 'Abgewiesen'
    end
end
```

For me (I am german) this methods are really important, because many of our clients don't accept the english enumeration symbol (like "unprocessed" in this example).

So normally I `include ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper` in all the controllers an models where I use the translate method. But I know that this is not the best practice.

Can you tell me how you solve this? Are there better ways?

Comment: Have you tried to use the `I18n` class? If you use this all your translations will go in their respective, language specific, `.yml` files and you can use the `t()` method, all you need to do is set your default locale in your `application.rb` like this `config.i18n.default_locale = :de` . Check out this guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html for more info.

Comment: You mean that I use ``I18n.t()`` instead of using ``t()`` with the include. Thats a good alternative, but isn't that also a workaround? Are there advantages against the include of the helper?

Comment: Yeah it is a workaround, but it's the one rails suggests. One of the advantages is that you could use the translations already available at https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n